# SQLite Full Text Search with Windowing (Paging) and Snippet / Highlight

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search, data-paging

I'm using SQLite's FTS module to try to implement a full text search with windowing (or paging as some might call it) of results as well as highlighting of the search hits within each window. As far as I can tell it's straightforward to have either windowing **or** highlighting of search hits, but not both.

To implement windowing, I run the FTS and retrieve and store the docid of every hit in a temporary table, along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE FullTextIndex USING FTS4 ( fulltext TEXT );
...
CREATE TEMP TABLE SearchResults ( id INTEGER );
INSERT INTO SearchResults
   SELECT docid FROM FullTextIndex WHERE fullText MATCH 'mySearchExpression';
```

When I'm ready to retrieve the actual full text based on the windowing criteria, I do something like this:

```
SELECT FullTextIndex.fullText FROM FullTextIndex
INNER JOIN SearchResults
ON FullTextIndex.docid = SearchResults.id
WHERE *windowing criteria applied to SearchResults*;
```

That part works great and is very efficient because it's a rowid match.

**However,** at this point I cannot make use of SQLite's `snippet` function (or any other FTS auxiliary function) in order to highlight my search hits because I'm not using the text index in the query. Therefore I tried this:

```
SELECT snippet(FullTextIndex) FROM FullTextIndex
WHERE FullTextIndex.docID IN 
   (SELECT id FROM SearchResults WHERE *windowing criteria*) 
    AND FullTextIndex.fullText MATCH 'mySearchExpression';
```

It works, but it takes almost exactly as long as the original FTS because it is apparently running the FTS first, without applying the narrowing criteria based on `SearchResults` (and I suppose fundamentally it can't because of the way FTS indexing works).

My best solution so far is to make a second temporary table - a temporary full text index containing only the search hits for each window. In essence this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.TextResultsWindow USING FTS4 (id INTEGER, fullText text);
INSERT INTO temp.TextResultsWindow
    SELECT FullTextIndex.docid, FullTextIndex.fullText
    FROM FullTextIndex
    WHERE FullTextIndex.docid IN 
     (SELECT id from SearchResults WHERE *windowing criteria*);

SELECT snippet(temp.TextResultsWindow.TextResultsWindow) 
FROM temp.TextResultsWindow
WHERE temp.TextResultsWindow.fullText 
MATCH 'mySearchExpression';
```

This does work, and it seems to be relatively fast for modest window sizes, but it seems terribly inefficient to be re-indexing a window of search hits just to have highlighting. If the volume of text in a particular window happened to be very large I could also easily see the window retrieval taking longer than the original FTS, just because it has to spend so much time re-indexing for each window just to use the `snippet` function. So while it works academically I don't think it'll be very good in practice.

Can anyone suggest a better approach? Plenty of applications have full text search with both windowing and highlighting. Do I have no choice but to just apply a manual scan and highlighting function to each full text result that I retrieve?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:
For what it's worth, there's a [section in the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a) that discusses FTE3/4 and `snippet`, and paging/windowing. They're suggesting using LIMIT and OFFSET to do the windowing, so the scenario they're describing would indeed result in the full text search being re-run on the whole index for every window. I guess if the SQLite developers don't have a more efficient way of doing this it probably doesn't exist, but still would appreciate any other thoughts folks might have.